# "I knew he must have been about seventeen"- Is it correct sentence? Help needed!

Tags: sentence-structure, modal-verbs, clauses, sequence-of-tenses

"I knew he must have been about seventeen"- Is it correct sentence?

I have a confusion with the sentence given above. Because as far as I know that if the main clause is in past tense then the subordinate clause must be in past form. If it is correct, I need to know why. Please some body help me to solve this problem!

Comment: There is no such rule. Your sentence is fine. It's perfectly correct to write things like: She said (past tense) that he is on his way (present tense) and that he will arrive tomorrow.

Comment: @RonaldSole Is it ok to write "I knew he is on his way"?

Comment: @Araucaria If you were asked when you learned that someone was due to arrive the following day, you might reply: **I knew (yesterday that) he is on his way.**  Or if a teacher asked pupils which of them knew that he is due to arrive shortly, one of them might reply: **I** *knew (that) he is on his way.*

Comment: "Must " in deduction doesn't change, "must" in obligation might change into "had to".

Comment: @V.V. So Are you saying that I should be "I knew he might have been about seventeen" ?

Comment: No, I just said when you use "must" to express deduction,  it doesn't change after the main clause in past tenses.

Comment: Also, this is a song Lyric from "I love Rock and Roll".

Comment: @RonaldSole I think that is incorrect. It should be "I knew (then that) he was on his way."

Comment: @JKreft But if he is still on his way, you knew (then that) he is on his way.

Comment: @RonaldSole "I knew then that he is on his way." is ungrammatical. It will get flagged by native speakers as incorrect. If you're telling the story in the past tense, you turn "he is" into "he was". If you're telling it in the present tense, you change "knew to know". "I know then that he is on his way."

Comment: @JKreft How about: I said then that he is ill.? Or: I told you yesterday that he is ill.?

Comment: "I said then `He is ill.'" OR  "I said then that he was ill." Similarly for your second sentence, it should be "was ill" or it should be a quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"At that time, I knew (that) he was seventeen." ->
"I knew he was seventeen."

These should look fine to you, as they're grammatically correct.

Let's look at the colloquialism 'must have been'. By using 'must have been', the author of the lyric is trying to insert uncertainty.

"he was seventeen" = there's a male, age 17.
"he must have been seventeen" = there's a male, probably age 17.

'about' just further enhances that uncertainty by making it "approximately 17": 
"he must have been about seventeen" = there's a male, probably age 17 (approximate).

So putting this together:
"I knew he was 17" = I'm certain he's 17.
"I knew he must have been about 17" = I'm pretty sure that his approximate age was 17.

(Also, take note that it's a song lyric, so some colloquialism may be there for meaning and some for scansion.)

Comment: Thank you so much!  Are you a native speaker?

Comment: @Omar Yes, I'm a native speaker.